# Reading items from Cosmos DB in C# script using Azure function - "Missing binding argument"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I've followed the tutorials for writing to Cosmos using C# scripts, but can't find any guidance on how to read any of the items in it back out, **specifically using the function-bindings from the function.json**

Here's my function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "direction": "in",
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "databaseName": "my-example-db",
      "collectionName": "Items",
      "connectionStringSetting": "my-example-db_DOCUMENTDB"
    }
  ]
}
```

In [the examples from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb?tabs=csharp-script#input), they show a `ToDoItem` type in the signature, but I can't see what / how any data gets bound to the signature in that way?

The compiler gives me this message (`inputDocument` presumably referring to my DB binding):

```
2020-11-23T23:54:28.431 [Warning] warning AF004: Missing binding argument named 'inputDocument'. Mismatched binding argument names may lead to function indexing errors.
```

My read script looks like this so far - but I don't know how to reference the DB input binding:

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    return new OkObjectResult("Nada!");
}
```

If I include something like `object inputDocument,` in the signature, I just get a 500 response (with no log / error messages).

Where my function writing to the DB had `out object outputDocument` in the signature, I have no idea what the type / signature syntax is for the 'inputDocument' is (mentioned by the compiler and in the function.json ?

For reference, the object schema I write to the DB looks like:

```
{
  "vocation": "Example",
  "places": 2
}
```

Comment: The signature will vary a little based on what you are trying to do with Cosmos. Are you trying to read a single document by ID?  Access multiple documents by query?  Do you know what version of Functions you are targeting?

Comment: @BryanLewis just a single item (matching "vocation") is the end goal.
I believe I'm on V2, it's a brand new function setup in the portal. Thank you.

Comment: @BryanLewis bounty and immense gratitude available if you have time to help me understand better. :)

Answer (score 0):

One way to read data is to bind our Azure Functions to containers in Cosmos DB which will allow the Function to read data from that container when the function gets executed.

[image]

Let’s say we have a Serverless API that uses HTTP Triggers to invoke our Function, we could get a document stored in Azure Cosmos DB using an input binding.

Here’s a way that we could do it:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using GIBDemo.Core.Helpers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using GIBDemo.Core.Models;

namespace GIBDemo.Triggers.Functions
{
    public static class ReadProductTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(ReadProductTrigger))]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "ReadProduct/{id}")] HttpRequest req,
            [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: Constants.COSMOS_DB_DATABASE_NAME,
                collectionName: Constants.COSMOS_DB_CONTAINER_NAME,
                ConnectionStringSetting = Constants.COSMOS_DB_CONNECTION_STRING,
                SqlQuery ="SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.id={id} ORDER BY c._ts DESC")] IEnumerable<Product> productItem,
            ILogger log,
            string id)
        {
            if (productItem == null)
            {
                return new NotFoundResult();
            }

            return new OkObjectResult(productItem);
        }
    }
}
```

You can read disadvantages, alternate methods etc. here: https://towardsdatascience.com/working-with-azure-cosmos-db-in-your-azure-functions-cc4f0f98a44d

Comment: Does this answer help you @Micheal?